# How to load text file into sort of table-like variable in Lua?

Tags: file, lua, load, lua-table

I need to load file to Lua's variables.

Let's say I got

```
name address email
```

There is space between each. I need the text file that has x-many of such lines in it to be loaded into some kind of object - or at least the one line shall be cut to array of strings divided by spaces.

Is this kind of job possible in Lua and how should I do this? I'm pretty new to Lua but I couldn't find anything relevant on Internet.

Comment: Note: the language's name isn't an acronym, it's a proper name (portugese for moon), so Lua not LUA.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To expand on uroc's answer:

```
local file = io.open("filename.txt")
if file then
    for line in file:lines() do
        local name, address, email = unpack(line:split(" ")) --unpack turns a table like the one given (if you use the recommended version) into a bunch of separate variables
        --do something with that data
    end
else
end
--you'll need a split method, i recommend the python-like version at http://lua-users.org/wiki/SplitJoin
--not providing here because of possible license issues
```

This however won't cover the case that your names have spaces in them.

Answer (score 11):

You want to read about [Lua *patterns*](http://lua-users.org/wiki/PatternsTutorial), which are part of the [string library](http://www.lua.org/pil/20.html).  Here's an example function (not tested):

```
function read_addresses(filename)
  local database = { }
  for l in io.lines(filename) do
    local n, a, e = l:match '(%S+)%s+(%S+)%s+(%S+)'
    table.insert(database, { name = n, address = a, email = e })
  end
  return database
end
```

This function just grabs three substrings made up of nonspace (`%S`) characters.  A real function would have some error checking to make sure the pattern actually matches.

Answer (score 3):

If you have control over the format of the input file, you will be better off storing the data in Lua format as described [here](http://www.lua.org/pil/12.html).

If not, use the [io library](http://www.lua.org/pil/21.2.html) to open the file and then use the [string library](http://www.lua.org/pil/20.html) like:

```
local f = io.open("foo.txt")
while 1 do
    local l = f:read()
    if not l then break end
    print(l) -- use the string library to split the string
end
```